# Using regex_replace to remove character in ansible playbook

Tags: regex, replace, ansible, aws-cloudformation

I am running a playbook in ansible that takes the stdout_lines of a shell module output and gives me this format:

```
StackNames.stdout_lines:
- "["
- '    "SHSD-CZWV-ami-automation-WIN2012R2-NONPROD-ramirja-119",'
- '    "SHSD-CZWV-ami-automation-WIN2012R2-NONPROD-ramirja-118",'
- '    "SHSD-CZWV-ami-automation-WIN2012R2-NONPROD-ramirja-117"'
- "]"
```

I am trying get get a list of these values that can be used in a loop so the stacks can be deleted, but first I need to get rid of all the quotes, dbl quotes and white spaces so is formatted properly for the cloudformation ansible module to take in the stack_name parameter value.

I have tried setting a new variable with proper formatting such as:

```
     - set_fact:
         stack_list: "{{ StackNames.stdout_lines | replace('"','') |trim }}"
```

but I have no luck so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, your shell command is returning a json parsable result. Simply parse the global output (`stdout`) inside a variable with the [`from_json` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#filters-for-formatting-data) and you're done:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    stack_list: "{{ StackNames.stdout | from_json }}"

- name: Make sure the above is working with your specific output
  debug:
    var: item
  loop: "{{ stack_list }}"
```

Comment: I this fixes your problem, you should accept the answer so others know there is a working solution, and eventually up-vote the answer which is the SO way to say thank you.

Comment: Done. Thanks for explaining the process, I'm new to it.